# Fetch records with distinct value of one column while replacing another col's value when multiple records

Tags: db2

I have 2 tables that I need to join based on distinct rid while replacing the column value with having different values in multiple rows. Better explained with an example set below.

```
CREATE TABLE usr (rid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE usr_loc
(rid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
code CHAR NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
loc_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO usr VALUES 
(1,'John','john@product'),
(2,'Linda','linda@product'),
(3,'Greg','greg@product'),
(4,'Kate','kate@product'),
(5,'Johny','johny@product'),
(6,'Mary','mary@test');

INSERT INTO usr_loc VALUES 
(1,'A',4532),
(1,'I',4538),
(1,'I',4545),
(2,'I',3123),
(3,'A',4512),
(3,'A',4527),
(4,'I',4567),
(4,'A',4565),
(5,'I',4512),
(6,'I',4567);
(6,'I',4569);
```

Required Result Set

```
+-----+-------+------+-----------------+
| rid | name  | Code |      email      |
+-----+-------+------+-----------------+
|   1 | John  | B    | 'john@product'  |
|   2 | Linda | I    | 'linda@product' |
|   3 | Greg  | A    | 'greg@product'  |
|   4 | Kate  | B    | 'kate@product'  |
|   5 | Johny | I    | 'johny@product' |
|   6 | Mary  | I    | 'mary@test'     |
+-----+-------+------+-----------------+
```

I have tried some queries to join and some to count but lost with the one which exactly satisfies the whole scenario.

The query I came up with is

```
SELECT distinct(a.rid)as rid, a.name, a.email, 'B' as code 
FROM usr 
JOIN usr_loc b ON a.rid=b.rid 
WHERE a.rid IN (SELECT rid FROM usr_loc GROUP BY rid HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);`
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it doesn't apply to a single column. It applies to the whole `SELECT` list.

Comment: Which are you using, MySQL, SQL-Server, or DB2?

Comment: You can't put a table name in an alias. `AS b.code` should just be `AS code`.

Comment: Example result set seems not well formed or, at least, it doesn't match with example data.

Comment: `rid` can't be a primary key in `usr_loc`, since there are duplicates.

Comment: I am using DB2. Sorry for my incorrect use of word distinct. usr_loc has primary key as combination of (rid,code,loc_id).

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by the users and count how many occurrences you have in `usr_loc`. If more than a single one, then replace the `code` by `B`. See below:

```
select
    rid,
    name,
    case when cnt > 1 then 'B' else min_code end as code,
    email
  from (
    select u.rid, u.name, u.email, min(l.code) as min_code, count(*) as cnt
      from usr u
      join usr_loc l on l.rid = u.rid
      group by u.rid, u.name, u.email
  ) x;
```

Seems to me that you are using MySQL, rather than IBM DB2. Is that so?